# Cancel Image.Source replacement if the condition in the Drop command is not matched

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

**Hi friends, I have problem when dragged Image is replace an image that implements the DropCommnad command even if the if condition inside the DropCommand is not matched.**

I have an Image in xaml:

````
<Image x:Name="chooseImage"
       IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
       Source="{Binding ImageRoute}"
       Opacity="{Binding BindingContext.CarImageOpacity, Source={x:Reference ActivePage}}"
       Aspect="AspectFit"
       WidthRequest="120">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <DragGestureRecognizer
            
            CanDrag="True"
            DropCompletedCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DragCompletedCommand , Source={x:Reference ActivePage}}"
            DropCompletedCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
            DragStartingCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DragStartingCommand ,Source={x:Reference ActivePage}}"
            DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding .}">
        </DragGestureRecognizer>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>```
````

It's base on CollectionView (cars).

And one Image for drop (where dragged image will be dropped):

```
<Image x:Name="FirstImage"
       Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Yellow"
       HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="120"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       Source="{Binding FirstImageCardSource}"
       IsVisible="true"
       Opacity="{Binding FirstCardOpacity}"
       VerticalOptions="End"
       Aspect="Fill">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="True"
                              DropCommandParameter="{x:Reference FirstImage}"
                              DropCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DropCommand, Source={x:Reference ActivePage}}"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

So, main problem right inside my ViewModel, there is my Drag and Drop commands:

```
[RelayCommand]
private void DragStarting(object e)
{
    DragItem = e as Car;

    DragItem.IsVisible = false;
}

[RelayCommand]
private void Drop(object e)
{
    Image takingImage = e as Image;

    // Get the image source string
    string imageSource = takingImage.Source.ToString();

    // Replace "File: " with an empty string
    string fileName = imageSource.Replace("File: ", "");

    // Compare the file names
    if (DragItem.ImageRoute == fileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something cool");]
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect match. Do not change the image source.");
        return;
    }
    //else code
}
```

**When a mismatch occurs, it is called a return;  but the Source of the image where the Drop occurred is still changed. How to fix this? I have tried everything (OneWay Binding varius Properties and others), can you help me in any way?**

Comment: Where is the code that change the image source?

Comment: I hope you're still here. 
Well, actually DropCommand replaces the Source of Image on its own. So this is the default logic for DropCommand for Images

Comment: Try setting DroppedEventArgs.Handled to true

Comment: Do as you said:
```
  [RelayCommand]
  private void Drop(object e)
  {
      DropEventArgs dropEventArgs = e as DropEventArgs;
      if (dropEventArgs != null)
      {
          dropEventArgs.Handled = true;
      }
```
But dropEventArgs is null. Well It was expected, since e in drop represent Image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve it:

```xml
<Image Source="dsc.JPG"
       WidthRequest="200"
       HeightRequest="150"
       Aspect="AspectFit">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <DragGestureRecognizer />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>


<Image x:Name="FirstImage"
       Source="dsd.JPG"
       BackgroundColor="Silver"
       WidthRequest="400"
       HeightRequest="300"
       Aspect="AspectFill">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <DropGestureRecognizer DragOver="DropGestureRecognizer_DragOver" x:Name="drop"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Code behind:

```cs
private void DropGestureRecognizer_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var i = FirstImage.Source.ToString();
    var j = e.Data.Image.ToString();
    if (i != j)
    {
        drop.AllowDrop = false;
    }
}
```

And here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/RZW9PMC).

I also tried to implement it in ViewModel but failed. Adding a breakpoint to run is ok, but runnig it directly will still change the image. It's weird.

Comment: OMG! That's exacly what I searching for! Thank's a lot Jianwei! ... world not without good people...
Ofcourse will be better for mvvm, but I will do it.
Thanks again Jianwei